# Parallax image not showing with data-img-src?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, z-index, parallax

So I've tried putting positive Z-index to get it to sit on top of body element, but it's still not displaying the image as it should.

```
h1 class="center">Parallax Effect Tutorial</h1>

<div class="parallax-window"  data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="./Home_BG.jpg" style="z-index: 100;"></div>
```

My CSS:

```
    body {}

    .center {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .parallax-window {
        min-height: 400px;
        background: transparent;
        z-index: 100 !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the **incompatibility** between **`JQuery latest version`** and the **`parallex.js`**.

Compatible Jquery versions:
**1.7.0** and above till **2.x**

Incompatible Jquery versions:
**3.x** and below **1.7.0**

Working fine with the following version of JQuery

> https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js

I hope it helps you